# python selenium, selecting links with same target

Tags: python, google-maps, selenium, web-scraping

Hey my project is this:

1. Select all links with `target=Map`
2. Store/convert www.streetmap.co.uk location to lat/longitude
3. Upload all to google maps

I'm getting stuck on step 1, can't even select the link and click it, please help

```
from selenium import webdriver

path_to_chromedriver = r'C:\Users\Kane\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)

url = 'http://www.fieldmycology.net/FRDBI/FRDBIrecord.asp?intGBNum=1511'
browser.get(url)
link = browser.find_element_by_xpath['//a[contains(@target = '"Map"')]']
link.click()
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting, also if you are interested in all the links you should use `find_elements_by_xpath` which will give you list of webelements.

Comment: changed element to elements, thanks. 

when I try to get selenium to select a single link and click it (to test if the code is working properly), it does not click the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @Gaurang Shah in the comments, you have to use `find_elements_by_xpath`

```
from selenium import webdriver

path_to_chromedriver = r'C:\Users\Kane\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)

url = 'http://www.fieldmycology.net/FRDBI/FRDBIrecord.asp?intGBNum=1511'
browser.get(url)
links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath['//a[contains(@target = '"Map"')]']
for link in links:
    link.click()
```

Comment: thanks for this, but the link remains unopened, despite selenium being told to click()

Comment: @balampam Check if your Xpath condition is working, that all elements are rendered on the webpage. If those are webpages and not element, check their href doing so : link.get_attribute('href')

Comment: I think @rak007, he have to come sape page to click on another link

Comment: @iamsankalp89 Then he should save all the href and do browser.get(href), do his actions and repeat